# Как объединить одинаковые ключи в словаре? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, list

Всем привет!
Python только начинаю познавать, вот и бьюсь 3ий день(

Есть список, примерно такого вида:

```
list = [['user', "data1"], 
['last_name', ' data2'], 
['first_name', ' data3'], 
['address', ' data4'], 
['email', ' data5'], 
['email', ' data6'], 
['address', ' data7'], 
['address', ' data8'], 
['email', ' data9'], 
['some', ' data10'],
['more', ' data11']]
```

Как объединить по ключам? (п.с. они могут быть разные).
В конечном итоге, хотелось бы получить json вида:

```
id = id

[
    {
        "id": {
            "user": 'data1',
            "last_name": 'data2',
            "first_name": "data3",
            "address": {
                0: 'data4',
                1: 'data7',
                2: 'data8'
            },
            "email": {
                0: 'data5',
                1: 'data6',
                2: 'data9'
            },
            "some": 'data9',
            "more": 'data10'
        }
    }
]
```

Пробовал так:

```
resultdict = {}

for key, value in list:
    try:
        resultdict[key] += value
    except KeyError:
        resultdict[key] = value
```

Но это лишь добавляет значение к ключу, а надо б список из значений..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По списку добавляются ключи в словарь. Если ключ новый, то в значение добавляется строка. Если ключ повторяется, то значение переделывается в  словарь.

```
dct = {}

for k, v in list:
    if k not in dct:
        dct[k] = v
    else:
        if type(dct[k]) != dict:
            dct[k] = {0: dct[k]}
        dct[k][len(dct[k])] = v

import json
print(json.dumps(dct, indent=4))
```

Вывод:

```
{
    "user": "data1",
    "last_name": " data2",
    "first_name": " data3",
    "address": {
        "0": " data4",
        "1": " data7",
        "2": " data8"
    },
    "email": {
        "0": " data5",
        "1": " data6",
        "2": " data9"
    },
    "some": " data10",
    "more": " data11"
}
```

Comment: omg! Это работает! Невероятно благодарен!